# What Easter eggs do the chat sites have?

Tags: discussion, chat, fun, hidden-features

According to [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha), the SE chat sites may have individual Easter eggs, depending on the site. If you find them, please post.

Because it's so easy to make this stuff up, a screenshot as proof would be nice. (Although Photoshop isn't that hard either...)

Comment: Screenshots? Really? We're giving you gold here, just go _try it out_.

Comment: Related: requests for easter egg suggestions on [MSU](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1476/pick-an-easter-egg-for-chat-superuser) and [MSF](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/818/pick-an-easter-egg-for-chat-serverfault)

Comment: Screenshots? My freehand circle-sense is tingling!

Comment: @popular Spoken like a man who can't do `Print Scrn`

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/Content/wheel.mp3 - Eggs.WOB.blame per "eggs.js". Any ideas?  Looks like the "wheel of blame" to me.

Comment: I checked the source of a chat room for each of the 39 sites listed in the footer. None of them have an "egg:WOB" attribute. So either the WOB easter egg is included on pages in a different way than the other `Eggs.*` easter eggs, or it isn't present on any of the sites I checked. If I had to guess, I'd say it's available only in secret moderator-only chatrooms. The Wheel of Blame is far too powerful for the likes of us normal community members.

Comment: I got one, but didn't realize I had to take a screenshot.  Mine said, "I want to trade..."  I was in SuperUser Chat.

Comment: I've found another easter egg, should I add it here as answer?

Comment: Ah, this egg is already noticed.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

**All chat domains, all rooms: this is fine**

Typing the message *this is fine* as-is results in server side rendering of the message into this:

[image: this is fine]

This isn't case sensitive, however formatted messages won't be parsed as a picture.

**Meta Stack Exchange/(any room): red tags**

Send a message consisting solely of `[status-SOME_PLAINTEXT_STRING]` and it will appear in chat like a moderator tag. Doing this as a reply to another message is okay, but other text or formatting will not work. The plaintext string cannot be longer than 50 characters, and must match the regex `[-A-Za-z0-9_]+`.

---

**Gaming/The Bridge: minigame `Eggs.Asteroids`**

Send the message `insert coin` and click on the floating "click me" button that appears to start an Asteroids-esque minigame with user avatars.

---

**Super User/Root Access: helpful assistant `Eggs.Assistant`**

[image: Helpful Paperclip]

Send a message matching the regex `/(?:^|[.!?:]\s+)(?:(?:how\s+(?:can|do)\s+i)\s+([^?!.:]+)\?|(?:i(?:\s+want|(?:\s‌​+am|'m)\s+(?:wanting|trying)|'d\s+like|\s+would\s+like)\s+to\s+([^?!.:]+)(?:$|\.|‌​!)))/i` to start an animation of a "helpful" anthropomorphic paperclip. Some other "how" questions will also work. (Yes, it's kinda crazy, but that's what balpha says the official regex is.)

---

**Server Fault/The Comms Room: system crash `Eggs.Console`**

Send the message `rm -rf /` to blank your screen out for a few seconds.

---

**Stack Overflow/(any room): insanity `Eggs.Cthulu`**

Send the message `<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>` to make quotes from [this famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) float all over your screen. Some other regular expressions will also work; the system looks at each attempt and makes a guess about whether it's an attempt to parse HTML or not.

---

**RPG Stackexchange: dice roller**

Send a message with d4, d6, d8, d10, d12 or d20 to have chat roll a die matching your input. This can be preceded with a number from 1-9. Chat will return a set of die rolls matching the dice expression used. You can also mix the expressions to get die of multiple types in a roll.

---

**Travel Stack Exchange/(any room)**

The world map preview on the bottom bar to the right of the message entry box zooms in and out based on how far the page is scrolled: scrolling up will zoom out, and scrolling down will zoom it in. The center point of this zoom changes based on your location.

---

**Other SE sites/(any room): search**

Searching for "easter", "egg", "eggs", "easter egg" or "easter eggs" results in a number of fake messages instead of actually searching for those terms. The results change each time the search is run. This works on all the chat sites

Comment: "makes a guess about whether it's an attempt to parse HTML or not" Using a regex, right? :)

Comment: @Popular, "How do I" on Root Access did not work for me. But "How do I launch Clippy?" (no quotes) did.

Comment: @Wikis, well, I did say "starting with." But the exact regex is `/^how (?:can|do) I (.+)\?/i`.

Comment: @Popular, I *started* a sentence with "How do I..." FWIW the first time it did not work. (The sentence was, "How do I launch the easter egg".)

Comment: @Popular Demand: actually, the exact regex is `/(?:^|[.!?:]\s+)(?:(?:how\s+(?:can|do)\s+i)\s+([^?!.:]+)\?|(?:i(?:\s+want|(?:\s+am|'m)\s+(?:wanting|trying)|'d\s+like|\s+would\s+like)\s+to\s+([^?!.:]+)(?:$|\.|!)))/i`

Comment: @balpha I am far too lazy to parse that in the afternoon, so just tell me: will "How do I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?" trigger that?

Comment: @Grace Note: Yes.

Comment: @Wikis, I see; in any case, balpha's provided the definitive answer, now.

Comment: There's always [Coding Kitten](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/533892/coding-kitten) in the javascript room, which isn't an official Easter Egg, but all the same...

Comment: There's something in the JS for 'WOB' or 'Wheel of Blame' - haven't figured out how it works yet, though.

Comment: Thanks @Fabian, my computer has trouble with SE chat so I couldn't test for myself.

Comment: Would RPG.SE's dice roller be considered an easter egg?

Comment: @waxeagle Yes, it would.

Comment: This also works (HTML+RegEx): `<[^>]*\[\^[^\]]*>.*\]`.

Comment: Wait, did something really write a regex to find regexes to parse HTML? xkcd.com/1313

Comment: I would love to take a look at the code for the Asteroids game.  it doesn't have infinite velocity like the original and you can't accelerate and turn left but you can accelerate and turn right....   is there somewhere that I can play with this without bugging that chat room?

Comment: @uɐɯsOuɐɥʇɐN it's enabled only in internal SE staff rooms, when someone type "It’s not my fault!" it triggers the WoB. See [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6814499#6814499).

Comment: The meta-stackexchange one works for Zalgo too , [status-Z̴͎͋a̴͠ͅl̸͖̀g̸̱̉o̶̩͆-̴̗̃a̷̘͝b̸͍̚u̴̇͜s̴̗͝e̶̝̍]

Answer (score 29):

Because this came up earlier in the Python chatroom: The chat script is made so all Easter eggs, except the activated one, are removed at run-time, making them inaccessible. On Stack Overflow, the activated easter egg is *Cthulu*.

You can activate *Cthulu* by entering a regex that matches a HTML tag. The simplest way to do that is by typing `<[^>]` into chat.

To get the other eggs work again, we need to hack a bit. For that, we will use the JavaScript consoles, browsers ship with. To access those, do the following:

- Chrome: <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + J</kbd>
- Firefox: <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + K</kbd>
- Other browsers: <kbd>F12</kbd> and then choose the console (<kbd>Ctrl + 2</kbd>)

As mentioned above, the other Easter eggs are removed at run-time when the chat loads. So to get them back, we first need to reload them. To do that, enter the following command into the console:

```
$.getScript('http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/Js/eggs.js');
```

After that, we can access all Easter eggs using `Eggs`. To change the currently activated easter egg, we can set `Eggs.Current`, for example to enable Asteroids, type `Eggs.Current = Eggs.Asterioids`.

But we can also just trigger the Easter eggs directly—without having to spam the chat room ;) The following list shows what to enter to trigger each Easter egg:

- Asteroids: `Eggs.Asteroids('insert coin')`
- Assistant: `Eggs.Assistant('I would like to start the assistant')`
- Cthulu: `Eggs.Cthulu('<[^>]')`
- Console: `Eggs.Console('rm -r')` or `Eggs.Console('del /s')`

---

Finally, there is the “WOB”, or “Wheel of Blame”. This one is a lot harder to activate because it does not seem to be integrated—possibly because it isn’t activated and as such maintained anymore. It’s still nice to see, so I want to give you the possibility to look at it anyway. Of course, this is not how it regularly works; it seems that it usually would be triggered by some new messages, but I couldn’t really figure out what the trigger exactly is. So my interpretion might be wrong, but it still works to see the Easter egg’s effect:

First, we initialize the easter egg using `Eggs.WOB.init()`. Next, we manully mark the last message as “new or edit”—this is something the WOB egg requires, probably because it would usually trigger on new messages:

```
var msg = $('.message').last().addClass('neworedit');
```

And finally, we can start the `WOB.blame` with appropriate parameters. The first parameter is the user id of the author of that message, and the second parameter is the message itself:

```
Eggs.WOB.blame(msg.parent().parent().attr('class').match(/user-(\d+)/)[1], msg);
```

Comment: The "Wheel of Blame" Easter egg is actually an active Easter egg; it's [only active in staff-only chat rooms](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=8279465#8279465) so normal users never see its true operation. It's triggered by someone typing "it's not my fault".

Comment: This is no longer working for me...

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Is it a regular expression or only the exact words "it's not my fault"?

Comment: @Anonymous Not sure. Would have to get hired at SE to fully confirm.

Answer (score 16):

Here is one I found on [Super User Root Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access):

I typed this in the chat box:

> I need to find a camera for a conference table. The table sits about
> 14 people. I would like to mount the camera permanently on the wall,
> so I am thinking a range of clarity for about 20 feet. It will be for
> video conferencing.

[image]

Here are a few more, but I don't remember what I was saying.  I took the screenshots when it happened though - these are real, and from the same chat room.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: He's back! Run for your lives!

Comment: "_so **you am** thinking a range of clarity for about 20 feet_" -- This guy needs to be taught some grammar lessons....

Comment: @CoolGuy: By integrating the MS Word spellchecker? :P

Comment: @NathanTuggy It looks like you're trying to integrate the MS Word spellchecker.  Would you like help?

Answer (score 3):

## Room Owner Only: I’m sorry Dave, I’m afraid I can’t do that.

Go into one of the rooms you own, and try to set a timeout for -1 seconds. You will then receive a notification saying "I’m sorry Dave, I’m afraid I can’t do that."

Screenshot:

> [image: screenshot of the Easter Egg]

Comment: Awesome find! But... Who is Dave? ;)

Comment: [Done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393298/who-is-dave-and-what-is-he-doing-in-the-chat). ;)

Answer (score -1):

Here's another one from Super User Root Access.

[image]

Comment: We don't even see what you typed because it's covered by Clippy's message.