# What's up with the Cthulu egg in the chat?

Tags: support, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Easter Eggs do the chat sites have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75861/what-easter-eggs-do-the-chat-sites-have)

Is the *Cthulu Egg* found in the sourcecode of the chat page mainly layed there for fun or actually used for something?

```
var chat = StartChat({
    ...
    egg: "Cthulu", // <---
    ...
```

Beautiying the `master-chat.js` shows that it is accessed somewhere but as we all know, reading (de-)minified JavaScript is as pleasant as a prostate examination.

Comment: Is this actually answered in the Easter Eggs question? I see no reference to it

Comment: @BenBrocka You just have to do some substitution: "Is the *`<name of the easter egg I saw on Stack Overflow's chat>`*..."

Comment: The Easter Eggs question lists an "insanity" egg, although it does not mention that its variable name is `Eggs.Cthulu`. I edited that information in; better late than never, right?

Comment: @Kevin, did you see my remark in the unicorn related question about this egg? Thanks for the clarification!