# The quest for the winter unicorn of the bash

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012, unicorns, easter-eggs

There are many rumors running about the winter bash site. Many voices of an easter egg hidden somewhere. Beards growing overnight.

Yet, one of the legend lies unspoken. The legend of an unicorn. A weaponized pony. A glimpse of glittering in the snow.

[image: Winter Bash logo with the purple mare unicorn]

Many have searched for the pony. Fewer have returned to tell its tale.

So now I start the hunt, for only a day remains. Find the glitter, and let the snow fall.

(Trad: how is this easter egg triggered? random? time related? any idea anyone? I notice that pressing CTRL draws snow to the pointer instead of repulsing it, but this is as far as I got).

PS: since we are at it, let's add a little subquestion. **Who** is the unicorn? based on the color my guess goes to Twilight Sparkle.

[image: Twilight Sparkle]

But I could be wrong. Still, there is a resemblance.

Edit: just to add meme to meme.

> ユニコーンは
> 雪にきらめく
> の冬の兆候
>
> Yunikōn wa 
> yuki ni kirameku 
> no fuyu no chōkō
>
> The Unicorn
> glittering in snows
> sign of winter

Comment: Did you try the usual Konami keys?

Comment: Tried them the second the site went up. And while we are at it, I still would like them to trigger the glorious unicornify script here on meta. ^_^' . Didn't work - but I found the pony at random, after leaving the page on. So I belive it is time related. Or RNG blessing related - which in turn would need for a ultra-rare shiny version

Comment: @TimPost - the logo is formed even if you don't press control ^_^' - you mean [Bubbles](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/meet-bubbles/), right?

Comment: And yet we wonder. Is the downvoter telling me that he don't think the unicorn is Twilight or that he doesn't like unicorn at all? Come on, have fun - It is the last two day of the winter bash after all, a little easter egg hunt cannot hurt.

Comment: Don't mind the downvote. Scrooge is about, and anything smelling of WinterBash will get a downvote as the SE equivalent of a mumbled "humbug". You may even receive a 'Too Localized' close vote, if you are really lucky!

Comment: At last it won't end like the [Chtulhu egg in chat question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136357/whats-up-with-the-cthulu-egg-in-the-chat), closed as duplicate of a question that didn't mention that ipotetical easter egg ^_^

Comment: @TimPost - ps, can this post be protected/closed after the Bash is over? I posted this to search for the unicorn and make more people see it (and have some fun while at it...), but after it is all over, there is no need to keep it open. Just please do not delete, leave it to the company of the archived memes - pretty please ^_^

Comment: @hims056, can I ask why you rolled back the closed question disclaimer? I added that hoping it will help to avoid the question begin reopened. Do you feel it is not necessary or there is a simplier way to protect it?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist - That is not the part of the question. So it should not be included in the question. You can add comment instead. :)

Comment: @hims056: I agree that it wouldn't strictly be part of the question... but I also belive no one would notice it if put in a comment.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Within the `home.js` script is the following code (indentation and comments added by me) :

```
function o(){
    function a(d){
        var e=Math.min(d-b,100);
        b=d;
        y.clearRect(-300,0,w.width,w.height);
        //perform one frame of physics on each snowflake, and draw them.
        for(var f,g=0,h=0;h<t.length;h++) 
            d=t[h],
            d.step(e),
            //f is "the last snowflake I drew before this one"
            f&&!d.target&&(g+=Math.abs(d.p[0]-f.p[0])+Math.abs(d.p[1]-f.p[1])),
            f=d,
            d.draw(y),
            d.p[1]>500/p&&!d.target&&(t[h]=c());
        //Unicorn drawing occurs here
        if(300<=t.length&&2E3>g&&!C){
            B[0]=s(0,0,1,2,0);
            e=D-120/p;
            f=200/p;
            d=420/p-E;
            for(g=0;g<H.length;g++) 
                h=H[g],
                h=new n(
                    {
                        x:e+h[0]/p,
                        y:f+h[1]/p,
                        time:d+g/40
                    },
                    $(j(h[2],"255,196,255")) //the same pink as seen in the OP's screenshot
                ),
                t.push(h);
            C=!0
        }
        I(a)
    }
    var b=v();
    I(
        function(c){
            b=c-(v()-b);
            a(c)
        }
    )
}
```

I have made some educated guesses as to the meaning of the obfuscated variables.

- H is an array of x,y coordinates, declared elsewhere, that form a
  unicorn shape when drawn.
- t is an array of snowflake objects on the screen.
- C is a `var` that is declared elsewhere but never assigned to anything, except within `function o`. So it is undefined until unicorn drawing occurs, and then it becomes `!0`. It appears to behave as a `hasUnicornBeenDrawnYet` boolean.
- g is the sum of the manhattan distances of adjacent snowflakes in `t`.

The crucial condition to make the unicorn appear is `if(300<=t.length&&2E3>g&&!C)`. If my guesses are correct, this translates to "If there are 300+ snowflakes, and they are very close together, and no unicorn has been drawn yet, then draw a unicorn".

Although the pink color and unobfuscated H array are smoking guns, I am not completely confident in my conclusion. I have not personally been able to make the unicorn appear, even after carefully gathering all the snowflakes while holding control. And the OP mentions the unicorn appeared for him after waiting a long time. But the unicorn should never appear, as long as `g` is too large.

Comment: Takes about 30-40 seconds of gathering snowflakes to get the Unicorn.

Comment: Great work, all your conclusions are absolutely correct -- and that JS is hell to deobfuscate :). Regarding the "even after gathering all snowflakes", there seems to be a rarely appearing bug causing a single snowflake to be somewhere way outside the screen, causing the distance sum to never go below the threshold. I couldn't reliably reproduce it, and since it's rare and really only affects the easter egg, I didn't dig too deep. Nice work!

Comment: Yay http://i.imgur.com/Y75O9.png

Comment: I just got it on my second try :-) I guess I just needed to refresh the page to flush out the bad snowflake that @balpha talked about.

Comment: Also, interesting aside: while source diving, I came across `return window[a+(a?"R":"r")+"equestAnimationFrame"]`. I was initially very excited to find a reference to an "equestrian animation frame"! But it turned out to be a red herring (or just poor reading comprehension on my part)

Comment: @Kevin actually it will return `a+"RequestAnimationFrame"` if a exists or `"requestAnimationFrame"` if it doesn't.

Comment: @balpha - not so rare. I had the felling it was something similar, but after the third attempt I assumed I were wrong.

Comment: I tried this a number of times (gathering flakes for as long as four or five minutes) and never got it; I guess I'll have to try again tonight.

Answer (score 6):

I got my UniCorn 2 Here it is [image]

Comment: All hail the unicorn. For the unicorn will bring the glitter on all is followers.

Comment: BTW, from its position, I would say that our unicorns are actually the same one. You see, it started on the left and is going to the right. Maybe it was the Cupcake Is not a lie hat that summoned it?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I got the cupcake, but didn't notice a unicorn. Then again (as you've guessed) I didn't spend a lot of time on winterba.sh itself, other than checking the leaderboards from time to time.

Comment: @SPArchaeologistyes it seems unicorn is heading towards cupcake but what i guess is that it will draw unicorn just below the area where you have collected the sparkles

Comment: I don't see any unicorn this year. :(

Answer (score 3):

Because the first time I tried to get the unicorn it appeared so quickly I assumed it want the special Easter egg I spent nearly four hours making the unicorn appear just before Christmas, to see if it would do anything in certain positions, such as horn touching the logo, nose touching the tree etc.

You can easily get it to appear just by holding down ctrl and waiting, but you can speed things up by moving the cursor towards snowflakes.

Turns out it is also possible to collect all small snowflakes while avoiding the big ones, and vice versa but it's hard work!