# Room design doesn't reset after quitting Asteroids

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, design, fun

I wanted to [play a quick game of Asteroids](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75863/287795), but after pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> to quit, the room display doesn't return to normal. See the screenshot below:

[image: astroids]

I remain stuck in outer space like this until I refresh the page. I assume I'm not supposed to be stranded like Mark Watney, so I would similarly assume that this is a bug.

For reference, I'm on Safari 9.0.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shoot everything to pieces, you live with it. Or reload the page :)

That's working as intended.

Comment: Okay, good to know. I guess I'm Mark Watney after all. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexA. Well he didn't *intentionally* break everything...

Comment: Clearly you haven't read the prologue. I'm pretty sure he said, "I was playing Asteroids on Mars and broke everything, so my crew left me there."