# Please, don't touch my eggs! (aka change the easter egg chat search)

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-search, easter-eggs

Recently when I've tried to search `egg` on one of the chat-room of SE network, I got fake messages, for example:

> [image]

All of those non-existent messages with negative ID, e.g. https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/0?m=-905743710#-905743710

I did find the reason in [What Easter Eggs do the chat sites have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75863/260388):

> Searching for "easter", "egg", or "easter egg" results in a number of fake messages instead of actually searching for those terms. The results change each time the search is run. This works on all the chat sites

So, I'm requesting to remove `egg` from this mechanism. By the way I think above quoted topic should be removed from easter egg or How about limiting to `easter egg` only.

Comment: I imagine being able to search for `egg` would be particularly useful in Seasoned Advice chatrooms.

Comment: I have changed the title to something I would have used myself, and added a screenshot. Feel free to rollback any of these if you don't think it's fitting.

Comment: @ShadowWizard There's really no reason to add 'aka ...' in the title..

Comment: @Insane yes there is. Jokes aside, title should summarize what the question is about. If you refer only to the "aka" itself, well, just a habit, if you want feel free to remove. (if others will approve I won't mind.)

Comment: As much as unexpected behavior like this annoys me, [Easter eggs exist for a reason](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118?m=33316643#33316643): "Writing Easter eggs and whimsical comments are a way for programmers to divert themselves away from the stress of doing real code. Programming is far more stressful than you think." Hence, I doubt this proposal will get very far.

Answer (score 9):

There's no need to do this, since you could search for `"egg"` (with quotes) and get proper results :)

(I have never searched for eggs before, but your question popped and I remembered you could use quotes with SE search to get literal results, so thought it would be the case with the chat search).

Someone who notices the oddity

> [image]
>
> (haha, how funny it is indeed!)

could (go / report it as bug) on meta or ask elsewhere, and (be pointed to / find) the question you've linked.