# The Winter Bash chicken Easter egg is broken now. Can we fix it?

Tags: bug, status-completed, easter-eggs, winter-bash-2019

Short story: last year the Winter Bash site featured a little Easter egg with a chicken - you can read more [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319928/the-lord-of-the-hats-the-return-of-the-chicken?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Now, we all know that this year's Winter Bash is a recycled version based on last year's. Apparently, in the rush, the Easter egg was copied too. The problem is that... something must have gone wrong and now the egg is broken - the encoding seems wrong.

[image: Broken Easter egg]

While we could just leave the link here like this, I would assume it *could* cause some confusion. Should we remove/fix it instead?

Comment: Well, the status is still 497 (Not a Chicken). So I guess the developer who made WB this year forgot to save the code with the proper fancy encoding which enables the unicode animals. :(

Comment: I am on it. This is obviously a very important issue.

Comment: All the other links work too (including the last one - deer - which still redirects to the youtube video) @ShadowThePrincessWizard. It is nothing to be worried about, but if someone finds the link and don't know the full story.... they could think there is a secret message to decode and waste time trying.

Comment: @Hitodama right. And the hunt for the chicken isn't a waste of time... ;-)

Comment: Has anyone out there actually checked out the routes from last year to see if they work after my "fix" was posted?

Comment: @YaakovEllis tried with chicken, pig and deer. All point to the same video now.

Comment: @Hitodama maybe you need to broaden your horizons, and go in search of other animals...

Comment: @YaakovEllis found two more chains - one starting with a random? animal and ending in a 10 hours of Sax video. The other one seems to have just one link - and goes to a very well known meme.

Comment: @Hitodama you are very close...need to think out of the box on this one (or maybe just out of the species)

Comment: @YaakovEllis you.. are't talking about the "All your bases" one, right?

Comment: @Hitodama indeed. you win.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easter Egg has been fixed

Happy Hunting