# My chat room appears to be hacked!

Tags: support, chat, hacked

[My chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216358/discussion-on-question-by-mandy8055-unable-to-make-the-mentioned-regular-express) started displaying weird text.

Is it the case with me only? I'm not sure whether this is the right place to put this question; but I was completely baffled by seeing that.

I guess this chat room is hacked. I went on to take the screen shot and the messages disappeared. I'm sure some of the chatrooms have been compromised. If this is not the place please let me know where I could put my query. My mind is not working right now. I'm sorry for this weird post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing is hacked.

The regular expression in the code you posted in chat triggered an [ancient Easter Egg of the chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75861/what-easter-eggs-do-the-chat-sites-have):

[image: room with animated text]

All is good, you can safely keep using the room and post messages.