# What are restrictions on screenshots from Stack Exchange that I want to post on my Blog?

Tags: discussion, legal, hidden-features

I run a blog with a friend of mine on Digital [Easter Eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)), and I wanted to document some of the Easter Eggs all over the site. Since it is possible that I might take screenshots of the same, I wanted to know:

***What are the restrictions on taking screenshots from Stack Exchange that I want to post on my blog?***

For reference, you can visit [my blog](https://huntingeastereggs.blogspot.com). (Disclaimer: The link to my blog is only to be used as a reference. I have no intentions of spamming.)

Comment: What is *Digital Easter Eggs*? Presumably a web service provider of some kind (not very search friendly). Or do you mean *digital Easter eggs* (*"a blog with a friend of mine ***about*** *digital Easter eggs"*) (though *"a blog on"* may be acceptable)? Can you clarify?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q, see - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q see also - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75861/what-easter-eggs-do-the-chat-sites-have?r=SearchResults&s=1|148.3315

Comment: @InfinityMilestone I think that P.Mort's point was that because you capitalized the first letters of "Digital Easer Eggs", it looks like a brand name or something like that. If it's not, then the correct way to write this (according to him; he's the expert :D) is "digital Easter eggs".

Comment: @41686d6564, you're right. (P.Mort is correct too).

Comment: A note about any possible answer/comment here (unless coming directly from an SE legal department or similar): whatever you do, *please do not treat any response shere as legal advice*. If you are concerned that your blog might violate the ToS rules, apart from considering suggestions here, please consult a lawyer and, possibly, SE itself via the "contact us" link.

Comment: @OlegValter, will keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the restrictions on taking screenshots from Stack Exchange that I want to post on my blog?

The [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) have a complete section about it (6. Content Permissions, Restrictions, and Creative Commons Licensing). In short, the TOS states that the content provided by the users is available under the CC BY-SA license and all the rest of the page is owned by Stack Overflow Inc. and may not be copied except for personal, non-commercial use and no derived works may be created.

It could be argued that a screenshot is a derived work, so then you would not be able to use a screenshot, unless

- you have (written) permission from Stack Overflow Inc. to use their copyrighted material in that way. Or...
- your creation and usage of the screenshot fall under permissible use under copyright law (e.g. fair use).

Besides that, you need to comply with the terms of the CC BY-SA license with regard to the displayed user content.