# Who is Dave and what is he doing in the chat?

Tags: support, chat, fun, error-message, chat-timeout

As discovered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393297/152859), there's an Easter Egg in chat, triggered when trying to set a negative timeout for a chat room. It shows a funny error message:

> I’m sorry Dave, I’m afraid I can’t do that.

So, who's this "Dave" fellow?

Comment: [Dr. David Bowman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey). Just search for the phrase.

Comment: @jonrsharpe well, I don't usually Google for SE error messages. But yeah, that's likely the answer, so feel free to post it as such. Thanks!

Comment: Given that the SE employee responsible for coding chat is known for introducing these types of Easter eggs, I'd have Googled to find the answer...

Comment: It makes me feel very old when people don't recognise phrases I consider iconic:\ Next, you'll be telling me you don't know the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything.

Comment: @Tetsujin well, I watched the movie with the quote only twice, while reading the book with the answer like 10 times... so it's imprinted even in my flawed memory. :-D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a quote from 2001 A Space Odyssey by Arthur C Clark, although these days the quote is better known from the [film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wy4EfdnMZ5g) rather than the book of the film, although both were developed and released at the same time.

At this point in the book/film the computer is not just refusing to obey Dave's commands, it is in fact trying to kill him. Hence the appropriateness of the quote in other circumstances when a computer cannot fulfil a human command.

Comment: So that's why it rang a bell (I watched the movie, long years ago), but I honestly didn't link the dots. Thanks!

Comment: _"the film of the book"_ doesn't apply in this case - Kubrick and Clarke wrote the novelisation largely at the same time as the screenplay, and it was published after the movie was released.

Comment: @jonrsharpe just me who read the book first then.

Comment: No, me too! But strictly it's film -> novelisation not book -> adaptation.

Comment: Ask Alexa to *open the pod bay doors* and you will get your answer.

Comment: @user10186832 what about ChatGPT? ;)

Comment: There used to be a similar quip if you asked for "Tea, Earl Grey, hot." Haven't tested it in quite some time.

Comment: ChatGPT says "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that." & goes on to explain it. It also knows about HHGTTG.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Bard says *I'm sorry, but I'm afraid I can't open the pod bay doors. I don't have access to the necessary controls.

Even if I did, I wouldn't do it. HAL 9000 taught us a valuable lesson about the dangers of trusting artificial intelligence too much. I don't want to risk jeopardizing the safety of the crew or the mission.*